# Not getting column headers on loading csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using the following code to load the data in python from a csv file:

```
import pandas as pd

df_csv = pd.read_csv("IMDB_data.csv", sep = ',',encoding = "ISO-8859-1", skiprows = 2)
```

the output that I get is this:

[image: output from the use of the mentioned code]

If you notice the header of each column it says 0.1, 0.2,0.3... and so on instead of "Plot", "Title", etc.
It would be a great help to me if you could help me understand why is this happening?
How can it be corrected?
What could be possibly causing it?

Comment: There is a parameter `header` that tells it where to find column names. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html. Try `header=0`

Comment: it is probably because of skiprows, one of the rows that is skipped might be the actual columns. In any case, you can get columns of the dataset and define the new df with the new columns. please share what checks you have tried and why are you using the exact hyper-params.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I was able to solve the problem by using the following code - df_csv = pd.read_csv("IMDB_data.csv",encoding = "ISO-8859-1", skiprows = [2]).  I am doing my coding on jupyter via anaconda and I learned that in order to get skiprows to work, i need to use "encoding = ISO-8859-1", after that when I put "skiprows = [2]" it only skipped the 2nd row which is what I wanted. Mistake I was earlier making was that I was putting in the value as [0,2] for skiprows which is why the header kept missing. i hope this helps.